# How to refresh the result order by choosing dropdown menu option in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list:

```
List<CompanyModel1> companies1 = new List<CompanyModel1>();
```

where CompanyModel1 is defined by:

```
public class CompanyModel1
    {
        public int compnSN1 { get; set; }
        public string compnStyle1 { get; set; }
        public string compnId1 { get; set; }
        public string compnKeySkills1 { get; set; }
        public string compnStandards1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I need to sort this list differently every time user click an option from a dropdown list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px"  
    autopostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1sel">
    <asp:ListItem Text="abc" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Iso 9001" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Iso 2004" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Standard xyz" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

For example, if click you on "Iso 2004" then it will group all the "compnStandards1" = "Iso 2004" and put that first and the rest later (re-arrange).

I know I can group it by:

```
companies1.GroupBy(o => o.compnStandards1).ToList();
```

But how do I sort all the results with the standard value "Iso 2004" in front? I cannot use normal sort here because I don't mean to use alphabet sorting.
Further more, if I need to populate options in above dropdown menu from the distinct compnStandards1 values is it possible and how ?

Comment: `Orderby` can be used here or your custom `Comparer`.

Comment: You can write your oown comparer, derieved from `IComparer<YourClassName>`.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: you mean "companies1.OrderByDescending(o => o.compnMastery1).ToList();" ? then how can I make sure the value that choose at dropdown list is group and order in the front ?

Comment: Are there `abc` standarts companies or this is a hardcode for alphabetical sort?

Comment: the dropdown as I mentioned, I am looking for the standard will be populated from compnStandards1. The "abc" is I just put there to make an example.

Comment: Make two Temporary list. list1 has a record with the compnstandard selected in dropdownlist and list2 contains the remaining one. After that add list2 to list1 so that it will be on top and remaining one at bottom and bind it back to the dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily sort your list dinamically in the handler for your `DropDownList1`

```
protected void DropDownList1sel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sort the companies according the selected standart
    var dinamicallySortedList = companies1.
        OrderByDescending(c => c.compnStandards1.Equals(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
    // for debug
    Label1.Text = string.Empty;
    // some work for the showing the companies
    foreach (var company in dinamicallySortedList)
    {
        Label1.Text += company.compnId1 + "<br />";
    }
}
```

Here, after you select new one standart, the list is being sorted by numeric index of the standart name searched in the `compnStandards1` property of each element you have in companies.

And you can get all the standarts by using the `.Distinct()` method, like this:

```
foreach (var standart in companies1.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.compnStandards1)).Select(c => c.compnStandards1).Distinct())
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(standart));
}
```

Rest of the code I've testing on:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    List<CompanyModel1> companies1 = new List<CompanyModel1>();

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        companies1.Add(new CompanyModel1
        {
            compnSN1 = 1,
            compnId1 = "Test 1",
            compnKeySkills1 = "Key 1",
            compnStyle1 = "Style 1",
            compnStandards1 = "abc"
        });
        companies1.Add(new CompanyModel1
        {
            compnSN1 = 2,
            compnId1 = "Test 2",
            compnKeySkills1 = "Key 2",
            compnStyle1 = "Style 2",
            compnStandards1 = "abc"
        });
        companies1.Add(new CompanyModel1
        {
            compnSN1 = 3,
            compnId1 = "Test 3",
            compnKeySkills1 = "Key 3",
            compnStyle1 = "Style 3",
            compnStandards1 = "Iso 2004"
        });
    }
    
    public class CompanyModel1
    {
        public int compnSN1 { get; set; }
        public string compnStyle1 { get; set; }
        public string compnId1 { get; set; }
        public string compnKeySkills1 { get; set; }
        public string compnStandards1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**:

My code was working with the label in `UpdatePanel` - it's being used for partial page update:

```
    // sort the companies according the selected standart
    var dinamicallySortedList = companies1.
        OrderByDescending(c => c.compnStandards1.Equals(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
    // for debug
    Label1.Text = string.Empty;
    // some work for the showing the companies
    foreach (var company in dinamicallySortedList)
    {
        Label1.Text += company.compnId1 + "<br />";
    }
```

You can easily add the ScriptManager to your page, using [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398863.aspx), for example.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px"  
    autopostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1sel">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As I can see, the code is working now, so you can use it as you wish. However, this is is not the place you'll get full solution for your problems. Good luck with this project.

---

About your problem with populating the result list:

> After getting companies1, I use your foreach loop to populate the option for dropdown menu.
> Then bind companies1 to display the result (it is a search function). The result is display when I bind the data to the repeater at ascx file:
>
> ```
> List<CompanyModel1> companies1sorted = companies1.OrderByDescending(o =>o.compnMastery1).ToList();
> companyRepeater.DataSource = companies1sorted;
> companyRepeater.DataBind();
> ```
>
> Then I want if user click options on dropdown menu, it will sort these results.

You have to repopulate the `.DataSource` each time page load as it isn't being stored in the `ViewState` and fire the `DataBind` event after each time, something like this:

```
protected void DropDownList1sel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // sort the companies according the selected standart
    var dinamicallySortedList = companies1.
        OrderByDescending(c => c.compnStandards1.Equals(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
    companyRepeater.DataSource = dinamicallySortedList;
    companyRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Make sure you have attached to the event in your code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200px"  
    autopostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1sel">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

For multiply choice, you can use cascading methods:

```
companies1.OrderByDescending().ThenByDescending()
```

Comment: That looks very promise, pls let me test, coz I am testing the dropdown menu code I use above there are too many errors...

Comment: I observed the followings when trying the code: 1)The dropdown menu is populated ! However I think there is a blank option (some of the companies may have blank standard field). 2)After clicking the option on dropdown menu, the search result disappear instead of resorting the result as expected, there is only a blank screen, is there any suggestion ?

Comment: Why would you sort by `IndexOf` rather than equality? It'd break if one of the standards contains one of the others as a substring, and it's (presumably) more work to check `IndexOf`

Comment: I updated with your modification. And I put: // some work for the showing the companies:
            companyRepeater.DataSource = dinamicallySortedList;
            companyRepeater.DataBind(); But when I click on one option, it still make the result disappear. Why is that so ?

Comment: After getting companies1, I use your foreach loop to populate the option for dropdown menu. Then bind companies1 to display the result (it is a search function). The result is display when I bind the data to the repeater at ascx file: List<CompanyModel1> companies1sorted = companies1.OrderByDescending(o =>o.compnMastery1).ToList();companyRepeater.DataSource = companies1sorted;companyRepeater.DataBind(); Then I want if user click options on dropdown menu, it will sort these results.

Comment: The updated is what I am using, as I mentioned in my previous comment. But I see the page flash like refresh but no result shows. One notice is, when I put the string in search box, I need to click "search" button to show the result, so when I click drop down option, it will not able to show re-sorted result, is it the reason ?

Comment: Btw, is it possible to choose 2 or multiple option in your dropdown menu ? As some case I need to sort by one standard first, then the second order is the second option user click.

Comment: the result will be display by binding the data in this function : private void DataBind_Results(). For your dropdlown clicking function, protected void DropDownList1sel(object sender, EventArgs e), I put it in front of  DataBind_Results(), so I think it will not able to show the result. Do I need to put it inside DataBind_Results() function ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57400/discussion-between-vmatm-and-user1314404).

Comment: I think your foreach to populate the option in dropdown menu is not complete, it only add the key but not add the value, that is why I never get it firing the function "DropDownList1sel" when clicking any option in the dropdown menu

Comment: @user1314404 1. This overload of `ListItem` uses input string for either the text and the value. 2. I don't know how the Ids are created and there was no such filed in your code. You can easily update it for your needs.

Comment: Ids is not important here, we only use standard for text and value in dropdown menu, just to make sure we do not have the same standard (same option) in dropdown menu, so everytime user click it will fire the function. Now the code never get to that function "DropDownList1sel", could you please update the code.

Comment: @user1314404 I can't understand the problem you have with this. I think you have enough information for fix your issue by yourself from now.

Comment: The problem is when I click on dropdown option, it will never go to the function (nothing change). It means that when populating the options for that dropdown menu, only the text is created, the values are not

Comment: @user1314404 In my code I can go inside the `DropDownList1sel`

Comment: Thank you, this is a perfect piece of codes ! Now I have it working and come back to give you kudo for great help! Cheers!!